# Pop-up window on click on button or text SP 2010

Tags: popup, sharepoint-2010

I am new to the Sharepoint 2010. I have basic understanding but not sure about the coding part in SP2010.

I have one contact list and I have one button on different page.

I want when I click on that button, new pop-up window should appear contains that only contact list and on window there should a close button too.

I have sharepoint designer also and heard that it's possible through JS coding but not sure how to do this and where to add JS coding into the SP 2010 or SP designer 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog for this requirement.

Sample script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenDialog(dialogUrl, dialogTitle) {
            var options = {
                        // define a URL (and yes, you can pass params to that URL) or reference your HTML object, but NOT both!
                        url: '/Lists/SourceList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1',
                        tite: 'Modal Title',
                        allowMaximize: false,
                        showClose: true,
                        width: 430,
                        height: 230,
                        dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallbackFunction
                    };
                    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
        }

function myCallbackFunction(result) {
                switch (result) {
                    case SP.UI.DialogResult.OK:
                        alert("You clicked OK");
                        // reload data as necessary here
                        break;
                    case SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel:
                        alert("You clicked cancel or close.");
                        break;
                }
            }
    </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="OpenDialog('url','My Dialog Box');">Show Modal Dialog</a>
```

Comment: Can u pls help me that where i should paste dis code? In SP designer 2010 . On my page when When i select text and click on code there are lots of code. I got confused that where exactly i shld paste this code to get activated on my text.

Comment: You could insert content editor webpart into the page, edit source and insert the script into the page, this can be done from UI.